# How to find the closest Eddystone Beacon with Nearby API?

Tags: android, beacon, eddystone, google-nearby

I have this Android application that detects Beacons using nearby API. I am able to detect all the beacons present in the area. How can I find the nearest beacon in that particular area? Is there any Google API that can help?

Comment: There isnt anything in the Nearby API that I am aware so you would have to resort to scanning for BLE devices manually and checking the signal strength

Answer (score 0):

While the Nearby API does not give you any indication of which beacon is closer, you can use the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library) for this purpose.  It has a Ranging API that tells you both the estimated distance to each beacon scanned, and the RSSI (signal strength) of that beacon.  You can simply sort by all visible beacons to find the closest one.

```
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                Log.i(TAG, "I see a beacon that is about "+beacon.getDistance()+" meters away.");        
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're talking about the Nearby Messages API, there are `MessageListener` callbacks which give you access to the signal strength and distance estimations of the detected beacons:

[RSSI and distance callbacks](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/advanced#rssi_and_distance_callbacks)

```
public void onBleSignalChanged(final Message message, final BleSignal bleSignal) {
  Log.i(TAG, "Message: " + message + " has new BLE signal information: " + bleSignal);
}

public void onDistanceChanged(final Message message, final Distance distance) {
  Log.i(TAG, "Distance changed, message: " + message + ", new distance: " + distance);
}
```

You subscribe to them the same way you subscribe to the `onFound` and `onLost` callbacks.

Comment: I tried working with them but I was stuck when there was no call to the above methods. Thank you :|

Comment: I got it , Thanks a lot :)